# Image capture while converting my html to apk using sencha

Tags: php, jquery, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I have html5 and php site.I want to convert it into android application using sencha.
I converted my app from http://www.sencha.com/ and working fine. But while image upload,it doesnot give option to capture image using device camera.

How can i enable device camera while image upload or any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow permissions for image capture in your AndroidManifest.xml???

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

I suggest exploring [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) to get a better understanding on implementing the above two lines